# Having problems blinking an LED on Arduino using information sent over CAN-bus

Tags: arduino, can-bus, arduino-c++

I've been messing around with CAN-bus to try and learn the basics so I can use it in a future project. I have 2 arduinos with MCP2515 chips connected that I am sending messages between.
I have been able to wire up the chips and send messages between the arduinos just fine, but when I went to modify the code to blink an LED if the first byte is 0x00 or 0x01 it wont blink. I added print statements to check that it is entering the loop, and it is, using the serial monitor I can see it yeet and yote, but digital pin 3 remains at ~0V.

This is probably more an arduino question than a CAN-bus question but could somebody help me understand why my LED wont blink? The code is entering the loop so it should be processing the command, and I initialized the pin to be an output, but i'm still not getting any blinking.

As a note, the transmitting arduino is sending alternating packets of data, first a packet with 0X01 as the first data byte, then with 0x00 as the first data byte. These data packets are separated by 5000 ms.

I am currently using the CAN library available here https://github.com/autowp/arduino-mcp2515

Code for receiving arduino

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp2515.h>

struct can_frame canMsg;
MCP2515 mcp2515(10);

int LED_PIN = 3;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_125KBPS);
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();

  Serial.println("------- CAN Read ----------");
  Serial.println("ID  DLC   DATA");
}

void loop() {

  if (mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg) == MCP2515::ERROR_OK) {

    Serial.print(canMsg.can_id, HEX); // print ID
    Serial.print(" "); 
    Serial.print(canMsg.can_dlc, HEX); // print DLC
    Serial.print(" ");
    if(canMsg.data[0] == 0x00){
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN,HIGH);
      Serial.print("YEET");
    }
    if(canMsg.data[0] == 0x01){
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN,LOW);
      Serial.print("YOTE");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<canMsg.can_dlc; i++)  {  // print the data

      Serial.print(canMsg.data[i],HEX);
      Serial.print(" ");

    }

    Serial.println();      
  }

}
```

and the code for transmitting arduino for completeness

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp2515.h>

struct can_frame canMsg1;
struct can_frame canMsg2;
MCP2515 mcp2515(10);


void setup() {

  canMsg1.can_id  = 0x0F6;
  canMsg1.can_dlc = 8;
  canMsg1.data[0] = 0x01;
  canMsg1.data[1] = 0x87;
  canMsg1.data[2] = 0x32;
  canMsg1.data[3] = 0xFA;
  canMsg1.data[4] = 0x26;
  canMsg1.data[5] = 0x8E;
  canMsg1.data[6] = 0xBE;
  canMsg1.data[7] = 0x86;

  canMsg2.can_id  = 0x036;
  canMsg2.can_dlc = 8;
  canMsg2.data[0] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[1] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[2] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[3] = 0x08;
  canMsg2.data[4] = 0x01;
  canMsg2.data[5] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[6] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[7] = 0xA0;

  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();

  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_125KBPS);
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();

  Serial.println("Example: Write to CAN");
}

void loop() {

  mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg1);
  delay(5000);
  mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg2);

  Serial.println("Messages sent");

  delay(5000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm an idiot. I forgot that breadboard power lines are not connected all the way down the board. I connected the Arduino to the proper section of the breadboard to receive power and ground, but connected the LED to an unconnected ground pin.